2020 Coleman ct100U
I have a coleman ct100u mini bike that has gas running to the carburetor but is not being sent to the engine. I have installed a new carburetor and clean all of the jets and nothing happened. I took the new one off and cleaned the old carburetor and same thing. When you pull the cord several times and then pull the spark plug out it is dry and not receiving gas.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you sure you have the jets set correctly? There should be idle jets which would be providing fuel during startup. If those jets are closed, your plugs will be dry. Also, have you checked to ensure you've got spark? Could be you're getting minimal gas, but no spark, which would not show up on the spark plug.

I have checked the spark plug and cleaned it and made sure there is spark there. I have moved the jets up and down and in every spot but nothin seams to change anything

Have you tried just squirting fuel down either to carb or into the sparkplug hole to make sure it will start that way?

Did this problem occur suddenly or after sitting for a long time?Remove the carburetor bowl and check for gas in the bowl.If no fuel in bowl the problem is either the needle and seat clogged, or the float is stuck.Basically,the problem is upstream from the carb if it has no gas and the above issues have been tested.
